# OpenNMS check if service is running on remote server using SSH

Tags: ssh, monitoring, service, opennms

I have an OpenNMS system configured and up and running.

I have a few Linux (debian) servers and I need to monitor if a specific service is running on them. This must be done using only ssh access. No SNMP or agents. I must configure OpenNMS to log-in on these servers and check if this service is running.

I've read about Polling, but I haven't found instructions on how to configure OpenNMS to access a remote Linux computer and check if a service is running.

Ideally what I'm looking for is a way to specify in OpenNMS, an IP Address, username, password and the name of the process I want to monitor.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [this SSH plugin](http://library.pandorafms.com/index.php?sec=Library&sec2=repository&lng=en&action=view_PUI&id_PUI=93) from the Pandora FMS community library.

It is a server plugin, read [this documentation](http://wiki.pandorafms.com/index.php?title=Pandora:Documentation_en:Remote_Monitoring#Monitoring_with_Plug_Ins_.28Server_Plugin.29) to see how to register the plugin and use it.

If you've never heard of Pandora FMS, check out their community website at pandorafms.org where you can download the Community edition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even though it doesn't answer the question for OpenNMS, I would love to give PandoraFMS a try. The problem is that, I think it may be an abandoned product. Their repository for Debian is not working, and their forums seem to be dead. http://forums.pandorafms.com/index.php/topic,9626.0.html Not dead, but noone is replying.

Comment: I have often published in their forums and I agree response times could be better, but I've always found a solution. Sometimes their engineers drop by and solve the questions. Check [their news](http://pandorafms.org/en/features/news), it's definitively not an abandoned product :)